# How to stop or crash an Android App in couple of weeks of Time?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, datetime, time

I am developing an App where i want a timer to crash the app after a month. The app should keep looking for the current time of the phone and crash the app when it reaches the one month limit.
How do i make the app crash while displaying a message saying "The one month usage limit reached" ?

Comment: Why not just check the current time compared to the time it was first run, and if over the limit display an error and exit.

Comment: Check in your activity if one month has passed, if not, then execute the usual code. BTW: we are missing some code that you have tried

Comment: Don't stop or intentionally crash the app, but make a screen with a message that the time limit has been reached and make an offer. Don't store this locally, or user can bypass the time limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is you are taking it wrong. If you really want a user to not install this again and have another free month you have to handle the Device / application couple on a server. If the user paid he get a licence, else he can use one month registered on a server. 
This is a huge security question, but just making a Timer in an activity is a bad idea. Easy to cheat by a 6 years old child.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the timestamp when app runs for first time in SharedPreferences.
2. Each time main activity starts, fetch current timestamp and calculate   difference with what you stored when app was started first time and check if it has been 1 month.

Another approach is to set broadcaster receiver for one month from current date when app starts for first time.

**Note:** This is not so good as changing time of phone or clearing data will result in app working correctly.

Comment: Clearing data will also bypass this.

Answer (score 0):

Save device imei (private device key identifier) and timestamp on server, nothing clean this imei (except some buggy device whit android 2.3 i think), but this will work, and don't crush the app just popup "demo expired, call me :)".

Comment: Will try and do this now. Thanks